# WebSocket with Spring 4.0 with MessageBroker and WebServers

Tags: spring, tomcat, websocket, rabbitmq

I've downloaded the latest version of the websocket with spring example from

https://github.com/rstoyanchev/spring-websocket-portfolio.

I'm running the application on Tomcat 8.0 RC5 and using the message broker RabbitMQ 3.1.5.
The simulation runs only 2-3 times after that the simulation doesn't work anymore, due to the below error. I tried also toi run the application on Glassfish 4.0, but the same error occurs. Can you please help what could be the reason?

```
15:47:35 [BrokerWebSocketChannel-1] ExceptionWebSocketHandlerDecorator - Unhandl
ed error for ExceptionWebSocketHandlerDecorator [delegate=LoggingWebSocketHandle
rDecorator [delegate=org.springframework.messaging.handler.websocket.SubProtocol
WebSocketHandler@1d2bde4]]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The WebSocket session has been closed and no me
thod (apart from close()) may be called on a closed session
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsSession.checkState(WsSession.java:642)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsSession.getNegotiatedSubprotocol(WsSess
ion.java:297)
        at org.springframework.web.socket.adapter.StandardWebSocketSession.getAc
ceptedProtocol(StandardWebSocketSession.java:113)
        at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.transport.session.WebSocketServ
erSockJsSession.getAcceptedProtocol(WebSocketServerSockJsSession.java:91)
        at org.springframework.messaging.handler.websocket.SubProtocolWebSocketH
andler.findProtocolHandler(SubProtocolWebSocketHandler.java:149)
        at org.springframework.messaging.handler.websocket.SubProtocolWebSocketH
andler.afterConnectionClosed(SubProtocolWebSocketHandler.java:224)
        at org.springframework.web.socket.support.WebSocketHandlerDecorator.afte
rConnectionClosed(WebSocketHandlerDecorator.java:69)
        at org.springframework.web.socket.support.LoggingWebSocketHandlerDecorat
or.afterConnectionClosed(LoggingWebSocketHandlerDecorator.java:74)
        at org.springframework.web.socket.support.ExceptionWebSocketHandlerDecor
ator.afterConnectionClosed(ExceptionWebSocketHandlerDecorator.java:89)
        at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.transport.session.AbstractSockJ
sSession.close(AbstractSockJsSession.java:237)
        at org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.StompProtocolHandler.handleM
essageToClient(StompProtocolHandler.java:183)
        at org.springframework.messaging.handler.websocket.SubProtocolWebSocketH
andler.handleMessage(SubProtocolWebSocketHandler.java:194)
        at org.springframework.messaging.support.channel.ExecutorSubscribableCha
nnel$1.run(ExecutorSubscribableChannel.java:80)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.
java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

Comment: The error should be related with the fact that I was using java 7 on 32 bit on Windows 7 (64 bit). After changing the java version to the 64 bit, the exception is not thrown anymore. I hope that these will help other people who encounter this issue.